# How do I access a posts's labels / tags so that I can add them to the page's TITLE or DESCRIPTION

Tags: seo, blogger

Blog URL: http://madhurtanwani.blogspot.com

I'm trying to optimize my blog's title and description tags and was thinking of adding the "tags" or "labels" for a post into the title and/or description tag (that is for blog pages are single posts).

I'm not aware of a way to access the "data:post.labels" data field in the  section of the template. If I could do that I can get the tags / labels and use them.

Can someone please help me out with this??

Thanks,
Madhur Tanwani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer for this one on this board : 
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/blogger/thread?tid=4f8c24d4ccf39a3c&hl=en